# Getting PHPStorm working with XDebug

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, phpstorm

I am trying to get PHPStorm to talk to Xdebug, and am having very little luck.

Here is my setup:
I have a VM which shares my php files from my local machine

I am trying to follow this:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/

I put the following in my php.ini

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_host = <my ip address>
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
```

It appears I successfully got xdebug running according to phpinfo().

I open my script, turn on the listener.  But when I get to the "Activate debugger on server" portion of the tutorial, things fall apart.  I download the firefox addon to start the debugger(this one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/), click the icon to start the debugger, reload the page, but phpstorm does not find it.  I also tried adding XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1 as a POST value yet still no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Edited, changed IP address to my localhost IP address.  In addition I tried to debug on my VM via vim, and nothing.  I don't know whats wrong anymore.

Comment: can you ssh from your host into your vm?  Can you open a webpage using http://ip.of.vm?  What happens is that the xdebug will connect back to your ide at the ip address and port# (9000) you have specified.  If it cannot make a connection to port 9k for some reason, it will not work.

Comment: Full guide here: [How to debug code on a remote server (or in vagrant box) with PHPStorm](http://www.dev-metal.com/debug-code-remote-server-vagrant-box-phpstorm/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want your remote_host to be the ip address that the vm sees on your localhost.  It's not the IP address you get from your ISP.

Comment: Fixed that and still no luck :(

Comment: found the issue, this was part of it, the other issue was my httpd conf still have the incorrect port value in it.

Comment: With vagrant, I've had luck leaving `remote_host` empty and just using `remote_connect_back=1`.